# Regex match word boundary string with parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a regex that checks if tag is inside the text, but there are couple tags (from multiple thousands, don't ask me why, SEO expert told my client its good) which end with parentheses.

The regex works great for normal tags, but plain fails on parentheses, as the match has to be exact, so I am forced to use word boundary. Is there a way to allow this?

Here is original regex I used:

https://regex101.com/r/wN9jO8/1

This is what I tried (yes, I am not good with regexes, but I tried googling and cold not find anything really useful):

https://regex101.com/r/wN9jO8/2

I also tried modifying word boundary, but it did not work correctly (always matched one letter of string in front and after the tag).

Basically, for the tag `text (jadad)`:

```
lipsum is a dummy text (jadad) alsdasldk. // match
lipsum is a dummy text (jadad). // match
lipsum is a dummy text (jadad) // match
lipsum is a dummy (text (jadad)) // match

lipsum is a dummy text (jadad // should not match
lipsum is a dummy text jadad) // should not match
lipsum is a dummy text (jadad)asd // should not match
```

The main problem is, it has to work perfectly fine for tags with parenthesis and without them, ideally easily editable to support more weird characters in tags ([ or > or tag ending with . or ? or !).

I am really lost right now. If you need any more info, just comment and I will try to add it in.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is a `tag`? `(jadad)` is the needle?

Comment: @chris85 sorry, I added it to the question. Its in the regex101 link, but I forgot to add it here.

Comment: So maybe `text \(jadad\)[^a-zA-Z]`? https://regex101.com/r/wN9jO8/4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead `(?!\w)` (means next position doesn't have a word char). Note that you cannot use `\b` as `\b` cannot assert after `)` which is considered a non-word character:

```
\btext \(jadad\)(?!\w)
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN9jO8/5)

Comment: Yes, but then tags which do not contain parenthesis (are just pure text) will not work.

Comment: looks like this is working fine :) I'll play with it a bit more, mainly tomorrow when I'll be at work doing with code (as I am playing with it in my spare time). If it will work (and looks like it will) I will accept your answer. I should look a bit more into negative lookahead  and all of those regex magic :P Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
\btext \(jadad\)(?!\w)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wN9jO8/6)

`\b` is equivalent to `(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)`: a position that is either *followed* by a word character and not preceded by one (beginning of word), or *preceded* by a word character and not followed by one (end of word).  You've got a "word" that ends with a non-word character, so you have to drop the `(?<=\w)` part of that word boundary.

Depending on your needs, you may want to change the first `\b` to `(?<!\w)`.  Also, be aware that `\w` includes digits and underscores (`_`); if that doesn't suit your needs, you can use a character class instead, e.g. `(?![A-Za-z0-9])`.

Comment: `\)(?!\w)` can be written `\)\B`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte no it **can not**, because it will **ignore** whitespace etc. Anyway, this is what I needed. I will give +1 to this answer, but as anubhava posted same thing earlier, I have to accept his answer, sorry.

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB: it can, it is an exact synonym.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte no it can not. Compare those 2: https://regex101.com/r/wN9jO8/7 (bad) vs https://regex101.com/r/wN9jO8/8 (correct).

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB: read my first comment one more time, you will (perhaps) understand. Better, read a tutorial about word boundaries.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Just fyi my original answer was `\btext \(jadad\)\B` but I changed it later to `\btext \(jadad\)(?!\w)` after OP's comment that `tag` doesn't always end with a non-word character. So tag can be `text (jadad)` and just `text` as well.

Comment: @anubhava: in this case, he must edit his question, that is actually unclear.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte As @anubhava said, it does not have to always end with parenthesis. And I have it in my question: `The main problem is, it has to work perfectly fine for tags with parenthesis and without them, ideally easily editable to support more weird characters in tags ([ or > or tag ending with . or ? or !).`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the regex101 because I'm on my phone, but this maybe is what you are looking for?

```
 preg_match_all("/(\(.*\))/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fo9

Edit:

Try this   http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fob

Edit2

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/foc

Edit3
With text (jadad) tag:

```
preg_match("/.*text (\(jadad\))[^\w].*/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fod

Comment: Nope, nowhere near. The tag is something like `text (another_text)` so its not just between brackets, it has to match a text that has brackets inside (well, `text (text) text` is no problem but `text (text)` is) and also consider word boundary.

Comment: Still no, I have to exactly specify the tag, its not just any character, but exact text that has to be matched with word boundary being respected. That's why I came here, because I have no idea how to make this work.

Comment: Your answer should be here, not on another site. Supplemental links are good but the data should be here in case the other site goes away.